# Why do I have to tell Adobe Brackets it's JSX, not JS, everytime I open a React.js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, adobe-brackets

Isn't it supposed to automatically identify the file as JSX? All the curly braces, html, etc.

[image: example]

Comment: Having worked with other editors, it's probably because of the extension name not being `jsx`.

Comment: There's an [ESLint rule to prevent usage of JSX inside `.js` files](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-filename-extension.md), it might be helpful.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I deactivated ESLint.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance I get it, but i already changed the file to be read as JSX, i guess it won't save that preference.

Comment: I just found an option to "Set as default for all js files", so that will have to do for now.

Comment: There's also nothing wrong with that since everything that works in JS will work in JSX.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Setting jsx as default for my js files didn't work, but I researched a little bit further and found that I can just change all the js file extensions to jsx, which won't crash React.